# Catching a constraint violation in psql

Tags: plsql

I am using sql developer, and have added a constraint to one of my tables.

```
constraint valid_gender check(gender in ('M','F','I','T'))
```

When I try to add an entry with say 'x' for gender using a plsql procedure, it fails with constraint violation (as it should).

I want to add a "Catch" to the plsql procedure so that if valid_gender is voilated I can raise_application_error specific to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

Oracle will raise an exception that says:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (yourschema.valid_gender) violated

You can catch that in an exception handler and raise your own exception instead using `raise_application_error` in a couple of ways.

1) You can specifically trap the ORA-02290 exception like this:

```
declare
  e_check_violated exception
  pragma exception_init (e_check_violated, -2290);
begin
  insert ...
exception
  when e_check_violated then
    if sqlerrm like '%(yourschema.valid_gender)%' then
       raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid gender');
    else
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

2) You can trap all exceptions and inspect them:

```
begin
  insert ...
exception
  when others then
    if sqlerrm like 'ORA-02290:%(yourschema.valid_gender)%' then
       raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid gender');
    else
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

In a large application it is quite common to have an exception handling procedure to generalise this and look up the constraint-specific message in a table.

Answer (score 1):

use anonym block in your code...

```
  BEGIN
    INSERT or update...

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
    RISE...

    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just test it first:

```
if gender_value not in ('M','F','I','T') then
    raise_application_error...
end if;
```